# How to know Validator earning solana (Testnet)

Tags: solana

Setup the Testnet Validator funded with some SOL in Testnet (Not real )

Here is the link for the Explorer
https://explorer.solana.com/address/GfudXfSxpvSBvkyNG7K1CdFhntZw3ASvBeCiTSRV5nzr?cluster=testnet

- Stake Account Identity :`EjGaPZ59sycMm46VpbukVY9PnwSdPYCfeQnbRLaZaD7m`
- Vote Account Identoty: `7R5of8HZreWPjURAMupJuik7vx5SAGUghpwU648bWYnt`
- Validator Identity:`GfudXfSxpvSBvkyNG7K1CdFhntZw3ASvBeCiTSRV5nzr`

The blocks are getting produced well in the Testnet Enviroment for the validator identity `GfudXfSxpvSBvkyNG7K1CdFhntZw3ASvBeCiTSRV5nzr`,

How to know the Validator earning where to check it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validator's earnings are stored in the validator's vote account, so check on the SOL balance in `7R5of8HZreWPjURAMupJuik7vx5SAGUghpwU648bWYnt`.  The voting commissions are paid out every epoch, so you'll have to wait until the next epoch to see rewards in the vote account and stake account.